# Symfony 4 & Doctrine, multiple relations with same entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

And Sorry I'm French :)

For my diploma I have to make a Tickets/Reports app and I'm stuck at the Doctrine mapping.

[Clone project on GitHUB](https://github.com/bZez/SF4-Monycks)

Here is my '**Transaction.php**' class:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TransactionRepository")
 */
class Transaction
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

************************** PROBLEM STARTS HERE  *************************

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 */
private $sender;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 */
private $receiver;

************************** PROBLEM ENDS HERE  *************************

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $amount;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",nullable=true)
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $comment;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getComment()
{
    return $this->comment;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $comment
 */
public function setComment($comment): void
{
    $this->comment = $comment;
}


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getSender()
{
    return $this->sender;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $sender
 */
public function setSender($sender): void
{
    $this->sender = $sender;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getReceiver()
{
    return $this->receiver;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $receiver
 */
public function setReceiver($receiver): void
{
    $this->receiver = $receiver;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAmount()
{
    return $this->amount;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $amount
 */
public function setAmount($amount): void
{
    $this->amount = $amount;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}

/**
 * @param mixed
 */
public function setDate()
{
    $this->date = new \DateTime("now");
}


}
```

And my '**User.php**' class

```
<?php
// src/Entity/User.php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\TransactionRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
* @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * The below length depends on the "algorithm" you use for encoding
 * the password, but this works well with bcrypt.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var Monycks
 */
private $monycks = 10000;

/**
 * @var Skill
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Skill",inversedBy="users")
 */
private $skill;

/**
 * @return Skill
 */
public function getSkill()
{
    return $this->skill;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $skill
 */
public function setSkill(Skill $skill): void
{
    $this->skill = $skill;
    $skill->addUser($this);
}


/**
 * @return Monycks
 */
public function getMonycks()
{
    return $this->monycks;
}

/**
 * @param Monycks $monycks
 */
public function setMonycks($monycks): void
{
    $this->monycks = $monycks;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

// other properties and methods


public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

public function getPlainPassword()
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

public function setPlainPassword($password)
{
    $this->plainPassword = $password;
}

public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

public function getSalt()
{
    // The bcrypt algorithm doesn't require a separate salt.
    // You *may* need a real salt if you choose a different encoder.
    return null;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    if($this->getUsername()=='admin')
        return array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER');
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}


public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
}

public function isSender()
{
    return $this->getId();
}

public function isReceiver()
{
return $this->getId();
}

}
```

My problem is that Users can have multiple Transactions as sender or receiver an Transaction have at least 2 user (Send & receive)

With this config, I can add **one** transaction for each user....
I still do not manage very well Doctrine relation yet...

So somedy can **EXPLAIN** me how to do the tricks and how it works....

[Clone project on GitHUB](https://github.com/bZez/SF4-Monycks)

Answer (score 1):

I finaly found a workinf solution but I don't now if it's the right way to do 
it...

I make a contrustor with two **ArrayCollection();** in my **User.php** class and I put users_id into.

And in my **Transaction.php** class **@ORM\JoinColumn**

In my **'Transaction.php'** class I put:

Everything is working now, but I don't really understand what's appened...

Someone can explain me correctly what was the problem .??

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="senders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $sender;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="receivers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $receiver;

public function getSender()
{
    return $this->sender;
}

public function setSender(User $user)
{
    $this->sender = $user;
}


public function getReceiver()
{
    return $this->receiver;
}

public function setReceiver(User $user)
{
    $this->receiver = $user;
}
```

And in my **'User.php'** class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Transaction", mappedBy="receiver")
 */
private $receivers;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Transaction", mappedBy="receiver")
 */
private $receivers;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Transaction", mappedBy="sender")
 */
private $senders;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->senders = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->receivers = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Transaction[]
 */
public function getReceivers()
{
    return $this->receivers;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Transaction[]
 */
public function getSenders()
{
    return $this->senders;
}
```